# bootstrap datepicker not working in django

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, python-3.7

i am trying to integrate bootstrap datepicker but its not working

setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'main_site',
'crispy_forms',
'bootstrap_datepicker_plus',
'bootstrap4'
```

]

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
import datetime 
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DatePickerInput 

class BookartistForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField(label = 'email', required=False)
    number = forms.CharField(required=False)
    artist_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
 artist_category = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [('singer','Singer'),('dancer','Dancer'),('comedian','Comedian'),('model','Model'),('celebrities','Celebrities'),('photographer','Photographer')])
#Event_Type = forms.ChoiceField( choices = [('question','Question'),('other','Other')])
budget = forms.CharField(required=False)
date = forms.DateField(widget=DatePickerInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'))
location = forms.CharField(required=False)
description = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea, required=False)
```

html template:

```
{% extends 'main_site/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
<div class="container">
 <section>
    <form method = 'post'>
     {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="bg bg-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

</section>
```

```
{% endblock content%}
```

also its unable to import on forms.py as i get error showing this:
unable to import bootstrap datepicker_plus

this is the output i'm getting 
[image: form output]

edit:

i have installed these dependency:

```
(venv) tboss@Tboss:~/Desktop/environment/celeb/celeb$ pip install django-bootsap4
 Requirement already satisfied: django-bootstrap4 in /home/tboss/Desktop/environment/celeb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.8)
```

requirements.txt:

```
Django==2.2
django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus==3.0.5
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
Pillow==6.1.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
psycopg2==2.8.1
psycopg2-binary==2.8.2
pytz==2019.1
sqlparse==0.3.0



(venv) tboss@Tboss:~/Desktop/environment/celeb/celeb$ pip install django- bootstrap-datepicker-plus
Requirement already satisfied: django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus in /home/tboss/Desktop/environment/celeb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: django>=1.8 in /home/tboss/Desktop/environment/celeb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus) (2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /home/tboss/Desktop/environment/celeb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django>=1.8->django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus) (2019.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in /home/tboss/Desktop/environment/celeb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django>=1.8->django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus) (0.3.0)
```

maybe this is error:
[image: bootstrapdatepicker]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question should be the other way around, the reason for your DatePicker not showing up is most likely due to the import error, so that's where you should start.

I looked through your code and tested it myself, and it seems to work fine here, so I think it's the dependencies.

Double-check that you have installed bootstrap and bootstrapper-datepicker-plus

```
pip install django-bootstrap4

pip install django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus
```

Stop and start your django server and see if anything has changed.

If you're still recieving the import error, please post the entire error report here, as I presume you typed the other error since there's a _ missing(or something's wrong there).

I would have liked to commented first and ask for more information, but unfortunately, I can't.

Comment: i have already installed these dependencies but i tried again see the edit though forms.py showing  error unable to import bootstrap_datepicker_plus when i type from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DatePickerInput

Comment: Since you're using a virtual environment it might be that Visual Studio is not looking in the correct place for your dependency.
I'm not very familiar with either Visual Studio or PyLint, but I suggest you take a look at this, as it might help you:
https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/troubleshooting_linting/

Comment: as i can see from python shell its importing                                              (venv) tboss@Tboss:~/Desktop/environment/celeb/celeb$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import sys
>>> 'bootstrap_datepicker_plus' in sys.modules
True
>>> import bootstrap_datepicker_plus
>>> 'bootstrap_datepicker_plus' in sys.modules
True

Comment: Can you import any other external modules(non standard django libraries) or is it only Bootstrap that is failing?
Try installing and importing Crispy forms or anything else really.

Comment: Can you show the error output from running python manage.py runserver?
If there is any.

Comment: its not showing any error also everything seems working

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, I don't see where the problem is then. I suggest you try to use another IDE to see if that's what causing the error.
My 2 cents are on the problem being VS not handling the virtual environment dependencies correctly.
Try another IDE or simply use Pythons own IDLE just to test it?

Answer (score 1):

you should import it like this:

```py
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus.widgets import DateTimePickerInput
```

Comment: It works for me after update bootstrap-datepicker-plus 3 to 4